# Cannot pipe to 'at'

Tags: bash, cron, at-job

I have a note programme which calls `echo 'notify-send Hello' | at now +1 minutes` however this does not work. I tried it in a terminal and, sure enough, `notify-send Hello` works, but `echo 'notify-send Hello' | at now +1 minutes` does not. What solution is there for this, if any?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strangely enough, replacing `echo 'notify-send Hello' | at now +1 minutes` with `notify-send Hello | at now +1 minutes` caused the programme to work seamlessly

Comment: But doesn't the second version send the notification immediately instead of in one minute? Nevertheless: If you solved your problem, please accept your own answer, if not, please edit your question instead and remove this answer, or people will assume you aren't asking anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Are you aware that `at` command output does not appear on stdout on your terminal, but is mailed to you (i.e. the user starting the command)? Is it perhaps in your mailbox?